# Rails add dynamic attribute on data content helper link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i need to get a ajax tooltip on a dynamic link, so the logic seems to concatenate it. but, still not work, so, someone know a way to do this?

thank's

```
<%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_path(current_user), :class =>"ttooltip",   :data => {:url => "/users/#{@current_user}/links"}    %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're string interpolating the current user object, which will call .to_s on the user object, which probably isn't what you want.

If links is nested under each user, you typically follow the 'users/:id/links' so you need to interpolate the id instead of the user object like so:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_path(current_user), :class =>"ttooltip",   :data => {:url => "/users/#{current_user.id}/links"}    %>
```

(Where current_user is a helper method that returns the current_user object.)

Comment: hell yeah! that' it. thank you very much man!

so, in this kind of cases aways interpolate.